# Divide a group of people into teams with constraints

Tags: algorithm

So I want to write a small program that would be able to take a group of people (100-200) and divide them into several equal groups (10-15) with constraints.

Each person has a city they came from (usually around 8-12 different cities total).
Each person was in a group of people before this new division (10-20 different groups).
Thats it for the example.

Now I want to divide those people in different group such that we strive to have same number of people from different cities in each team (so not all new yorkes are in the same team etc) and strive that people who have been in the same team before wont team up again.

Cant find an algorithm that can help me.

Comment: depends on what "strive" means in this context.  You could divide people into groups by city (so one of each city is in a group and no more) then randomly shuffle those same-city member's order and place them in order into groups.  There you have strived to randomize the groups in a simple way.

Comment: I suggest you work through an example on pieces of paper... not hard.  Posting here without even an attempt at an algorithm - or concrete problems you encountered deriving one - is pretty poor form....

Answer (score 1):

There is an np-complete feeling about finding an absolute best answer.  But you just want a pretty good answer, pretty fast, it isn't hard to come up with a heuristic.

Set up your empty teams.  Decide on the maximum team size.  Sort people by the number of other people to avoid (same city or past same team) descending.  Put each person in the non-full team with the least other people you are trying to avoid, breaking ties for the team with smaller people, and randomly breaking any remaining ties.

This is not guaranteed to produce optimal results.  But it is simple and will produce pretty good ones.