# Best way of forming r groups from a team of n people, but minimising overlap

Tags: python, r, combinatorics

I was recently asked the following seemingly simple question: What is the best way to partition a team of 12 people into groups of three, where the process is to be repeated 6 times? The solution should minimize the number of times two people are put together in the same team. The total number of combinations is given by,

```
nCr = 12!/(3! * (12-3)!) = 220
```

so finding a solution by hand is not really a practical proposition. The most practical (and simplistic) solution that I found was to shuffle the 12 names and select the groups from the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th triples. Then run the process 6 times. This did solve the problem, but there were too many situations where two people were put together in the same group, after consecutive runs. A general solution (groups of r from n) would be nice.

I have also posted this on "Computational Science" but they feel it belongs elsewhere.
I have looked at [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133372/divide-a-group-of-people-into-teams-with-constraints) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927681/generate-teams-of-a-group) but these solutions do not seem to solve my particular problem.

Comment: maybe more suited for statexchange?

Comment: To get a random result you could do `lapply(1:6, function(i) matrix(sample(1:12), 3, 4))` But probably it's better to ask this on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Here is a possible starting point: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435341/divide-120-students-into-12-groups-for-6-workshops-without-repeating/1435777#1435777

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a variant of the "Social Golfer Problem", which is an open problem in ***graph theory***. Many thanks to [Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244/dave2e) who provided a clue to its solution by the [Link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435341/divide-120-students-into-12-groups-for-6-workshops-without-repeating/1435777#1435777). This link leads to two more excellent discussions of the problem at [Link2](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/) and [Link3](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html).

Comment: Thank goodness for that. I have tried several times to solve your problem programatically and couldn't get past four days of scheduling. I knew six was impossible but thought there was probably a way to get five days then repeat day one as the optimal solution. It seems from the links that this isn't possible, so I can stop beating myself up!

Comment: It was also a great relief to me when I found it was an open problem and I had to be satisfied with a sub-optimal solution.